# How do you sample from a half-normal distribution in Python?

Tags: distributions, scipy, numpy

I would like to generate samples from a half normal distribution.

numpy's random number generator allows you to sample from many distributions. Here's an example for the normal distribution. However, it does not appear to support half-normal. I could take the absolute value of the samples, but this seems inelegant.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

samples = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=1000)
plt.hist(samples)
```

scipy contains a half-normal distribution (halfnorm), but I can't figure out if you are able to sample from this.

```
from scipy.stats import halfnorm, norm
```

Comment: Why are you thinking $|X|$ for $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ is inelegant ? You are just using the definition of the half-normal distribution unless you are thinking this definition is inelegant...

Comment: Use `halfnorm.rvs(loc = 0, scale = 1, size = 10000)` (the `rvs` method) for example to generate random variables. Found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.halfnorm.html).

Comment: @utobi now that you mention it, it's not bad.

Comment: @COOLSerdash this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you want to add this as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.halfnorm.html) states the `rvs` method to calculate random variables from a half-normal distribution. For example:

```
from scipy.stats import halfnorm, norm
x = halfnorm.rvs(loc = 0, scale = 1, size=1000)
```

Here, `loc` specifies the location and `scale` the scale parameters.